# Passing a string as argument in new environment

Tags: environments

I'm actually trying to pass a string as an argument in a new environment, but it seems that it only takes the first letter of my string.

Here's my code, where **#1** is usually a path (for example *img/pic.png*):

```
\newenvironment{backcover}[1]
  {\backlayout{#1}}
  {}
```

I get multiple errors given if I change the numbers, for instance if it is #2, the string becomes **i**, for #3 it is **m**, etc...

Example of use :

```
\begin{backcover}[img/pic.png]
  Hello
\end{backcover}
```

What did I miss ?

*Sorry if that has already been answered, it's been two hours and I couldn't find a way to fix this problem on SX or anywhere else.*

Comment: The syntax is `\newenvironment{backcover}[1]...` (no # here)

Comment: Yes sorry, bad copy-paste, editing this right now

Comment: Well if this wasn't the source of your troubles it is somewhere else you will have to make a complete example which also shows how you actually use the environment.

Comment: it would seem you are calling this as `\begin{backcover}img/pic` in which case `#1` is just `i` the syntax is `\begin{backcover}{img/pic}` so `#1` is `img/pic` but you haven't shown any code that demonstrates the error so it is hard to guess.

Comment: Yes sorry (never posted in SX), adding example in edit !

Comment: You are declaring a mandatory argument, so you should use normal braces and not brackets. `\begin{backover}{img/pic.png}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well that's a solution, thanks !

Comment: @Zarov the edit is better (answer in Ulrike's comment or mine) but it would have better to have posted a complete small document with (any) definition of `\backlayout` and `\documentclass`... `\end{document}` so people could run the code without guessing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle will do next time then ! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **UlrikeFischer**

As it is a mandatory argument, I need to call it like this, with braces and not brackets :

```
\begin{backcover}{img/pic.png}
  Hello
\end{backcover}
```